# Configure resharper/visual studio to highlight specific parts of a strings in javascript files (like in string.format of C#)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper, syntax-highlighting, configure

In javascript we have a utility method called stringFormat which works as such:

stringFormat("Some template {0}.", someNumber);

Is there any way to tweak resharper so that {0} gets highlighted in the same fashion that resharper (or visual studio in general) highlights like it does in C# string.format?